# How to put iframe or some its substitute at Jenkins ver. 2.176.2?

Tags: html, jenkins, iframe

I would like to put into my Jenkins view another HTML, and tried to do this that way, adding that as a text section:

```
<iframe style="border: 0;position: relative;" width=1000px height=300px src="http://my_source.html">
Error
</iframe>
```

And I see it doesn't work, it doesn't even show on the view's source. Another part of HTML code put into text section works fine. I found that XFrame-Filter plugin configured to ALLOW-FROM http://my_source.html can solve that problem, but unfortunately it doesn't. Putting that content by object or link rel doesn't work too. At this moment, I have no idea how to make it work. Could you help me with that?

Comment: Is one of your websites https and other http?

Comment: @Gifron oh, I haven't mentioned that - my_source is the same site where my jenkins is, and both are http.

Comment: Have you reviewed:[Configuring Content Security Policy](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy) ?